# How to fail maven build only if the scenarios are failed on rerun

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I'm using Cucumber and JUnit together in my selenium automation project. Since i have flaky test cases, i have added retry runs to the project. By adding the class below:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = { "@target/rerun.txt" },
               glue = { "stepDefinitions" }, 
               monochrome = true, plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-reports",
               "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json", "junit:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.xml",
               "json:target/cucumber.json",
               "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"})

public class TestRunnerRerunCucumber {

}
```

I also need to fail the maven build, if any of the test cases are failed **except the ones that passed on rerun**.  But when a test case fails on the first run and passes on the second run, maven build still fails. I have used maven surefire plugin to fail the build:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Cucumber.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Is there any configurations or plugins to success the maven build if failed test cases pass on rerun?

Comment: If you can [ingtegrate your cucumber-test-cases into junit (4.x) ones](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/#junit-integration), then you could easy go with [this option](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html)(`rerunFailingTestsCount`)

Comment: After i deleted TestRunnerRerunCucumber  class, this worked perfectly.